# Inserting a variable into a shortcode inside php

Tags: shortcode, embed

```
$idstring = do_shortcode( $cb_video_url );
```

long story short, this gets the YouTube video ID from a given url (example: 5kx45jHqQ )

and there is a youtube embed plugin for wordpress that uses the shortcode format:

```
[youtube]videoID[/youtube]
```

I want to put the dynamic youtube video ID from URL($idstring variable) in between these 2 shortcode tags...

I'm trying really hard and I've tried everything. Maybe there's something wrong and you can help. So please if you have a solution.

Furthest I've got is getting them to display on site in text form.... Literally `[youtube]5kx45jHqQ[/youtube]`

Comment: Show us your full shortcode code, the logic that runs your `[youtube]` shortcode. **EDIT** Sorry, I just re-read that, are you using a plugin for this shortcode instead? Or did you create it yourself?

Comment: Try using `do_shortcode( '[youtube]' . $idstring . '[/youtube] );`

Comment: thank you so much for responding. Your code is absolutely right!!
But while I thought the problem was in the code... it was actually in the plugin, or two! JETPACK was conflicting with this specific shortcode [youtube] and it was the reason nothing was showing.

The solution was to either disable Jetpacks Shortcode extension OR use an alternative [youtube_video][/youtube_video] shortcode and it worked!